How to choose the correct base voltage to "turn on" a transistor (and why does my circuit behave badly with a higher voltage)?
The circuit below is designed to flash the LED on the right such that the flash rate increases when the voltage at the STATUS input on the left is taken from 0 to +3.2V (connected to a GPIO pin on a raspberry pi). My idea was to use a basic 555 timer circuit (on/off times controlled by R1, R2) and use two 2N3904 NPN transistors as simple switches to bring R1' and R2' in parallel with R1 and R2, decreasing the overall resistances and thus also decreasing the one/off times.

And it works. But what I discovered (by trial and error) was that if the voltage across Rb is a bit too high the LED turns off entirely. This I was not expecting. As luck would have it, 3.2V seems to be on the cusp of "too high". In my original circuit, Rb was 10K (included only as a pulldown for the 0V input state) and Ra was not present at all (just a wire). And that worked, some of the time (it worked on a breadboard, it got flakey when I soldered onto perfboard). The current version uses Ra = Rb = 10k. I am aware that a transistor is not a simple switch but I naively thought that I could get away with treating it like one here. I checked as best I could that 3.2V would not fry anything and (basically) crossed my fingers that it would be high enough to switch the transistors on.
It's nice that I got the circuit working, but I would really like to understand it better.

For context, if you can already control the Rasberry Pi, why not hook the LED up directly to the Pi and control it in software; what vale does all that circuitry provide between the Pi and the LED that the Pi can't do alone?

Because I want the LED to blink slowly when the Pi has been shutdown, then for the rate to increase when it starts to boot. I've used physical pin 8 on the Pi for the status input, which is at 0 when the Pi has shutdown and goes high as soon as it powers up. I also have an extra bit of circuitry (omitted in the question for simplicity) which uses a another GPIO pin (controlled in software) to latch the timer on once the Pi's wlan interface comes up. So: power-connected-but-Pi-shutdown=slow-blink, booting=rapid-blink, wlan-up=solid-on. But honestly, I just wanted to see if I could make it work.

The 555 output goes low (resets) when its pin 6 (THES) voltage goes above 2/3 the supply voltage or 3.33V with a 5V supply, which explains why the LED stays off when the transistor voltage goes above 3.2V.

@CarlRutschow thanks, that makes sense of the "coincidence" of 3.2V being just on the cusp. I wasn't even seeing the connection between the status voltage and the voltage at pin 6.

Start with the Status input, and follow the current path all the way to the discharge pin.
There are two resistance paths connected to C.  One is through R2, which is grounded through the Discharge output whenever the 555 output is high.  The other is R'2 back to the Thevenin equivalent resistance of Ra and Rb, and the resulting Thevenin equivalent voltage at the Ra-Rb node.  This is essentially one long voltage divider string (with a diode thrown in).
If the status voltage and Rb both are high enough, R'2 is low enough, and R2 is high enough, the voltage across C never will be less than 0.333Vcc.  This is the voltage level at which the 555 output changes from low (LED-off) to high.
You already have the solution:  adjust the various resistors such that the peak-to-peak voltage across C exceeds the 555 minimum operating range, 1/3 x Vcc to 2/3 x Vcc.

"follow the current path...": this is really helpful. I wasn't following the base-emitter current path (I really was thinking of the transistors as switches). "This is essentially one long voltage divider string (with a diode thrown in)": also really helpful. Thank you. (I would like to vote this answer up but I have zero rep, so I can't.)

Thanks for the Check.  Any follow-up questions?
